# Help! My cat broke the seed pod off my mango seedling, Will it still grow?

Tags: fruit-trees

As I was planting my mango seedling I kept the seed above the soil because I liked the look of it it was really silly as my cat jumped up and paw landed on the pod snapping the pod off! 
The mango seedling is about 2 inches tall with 8 leaves that still look rather healthy despite the seed pod being broken off 3 days ago, I also know that it has a very strong root.
Does anyone know if my plant Will Survive or not??

Comment: It depends as you're applying S.T.U.N. to it. S.T.U .N. - https://permaculturenews.org/2013/06/07/mark-shepards-proven-technique-sheer-total-and-utter-neglect/

Comment: I'm just watching to see what happens now if that's what you mean?